# "CKSubscriptionTypeRecordZone subscriptions are incompatible with subscription options 7" when creating a subscription

Tags: ios8, cloudkit, cksubscription

I'm trying to use the following code to create a CloudKit subscription:

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let database = container.publicCloudDatabase
let recordZone = CKRecordZone.defaultRecordZone()

let subscription = CKSubscription(zoneID: recordZone.zoneID, options: .FiresOnRecordCreation | .FiresOnRecordUpdate | .FiresOnRecordDeletion)

database.saveSubscription(subscription) {(subscription: CKSubscription!, error: NSError!) in
    if error
    {
        NSLog("Error: %@", error)
    }
    else if subscription
    {
        NSLog("Saved subscription: %@", subscription)
    }
}
```

And it fails with this error:

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'CKSubscriptionTypeRecordZone subscriptions are incompatible with subscription options 7'`

What does this mean, and how can I fix it? I want to be notified when a record is created, updated, or deleted.

Comment: I suppose you could create multiple subscriptions, but I'd expect to find this explicitly stated somewhere, and I can't find anything. For what it's worth, it crashes for any value that isn't 1,2,4 or 8 indicating there's no support to ORing the options together, which I wasn't expecting, but I suppose that's the way it is.

Comment: I figured it out, @0x7fffffff - it's right there in the docs. I should start reading those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duh! From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKSubscription_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKSubscription/initWithZoneID:options:):

> `subscriptionOptions`
>
> The configuration options for the subscription. You must specify 0 for this parameter. Zone subscriptions currently do not support any options.

Specifying `nil` works, although I'm probably going to take a different approach.